# How to Show Admob ad block if Admob ad is empty?

Tags: react-native, admob

I want to make a function which will check if **Admob ad** is empty  show another **Admob ad block**.
How can I do it ?

Code:

```js
//...
class MediumAdmobAd extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          !this.state.hasAd ? (
            // main add
          ) : (
            <View>
              {/* Another ad if first ad is not finding */}
            </View>
          )
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default MediumAdmobAd;
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as conditional rendering as follows:

```
render(){
 return(
  <View>
    ....
    {!this.state.hasAd && <showAd/>}
    ....
  </View>
 )
}
```